# Jython can't detect python files inside a subdirectory

Tags: python, jython-2.7

I have already tried appending the path to sys.path, but that doesn't solve the problem either. The import works fine with my Python36 interpreter.

My directory structure is:

project (dir)

:main.py

:=> Algorithms (sub-dir)

:==> AlgoOne.py

My code in the entry file which is one level above the Algorithms dir is:

```
#main.py
from Algorithms.AlgoOne.py import ClassOne
```

Any ideas why this could happen, or how I instruct jython to read the directory as a module like Python36?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an empty `__init__.py` file in that directory? It is needed for Python 2.x to recognize a directory as a package.

Comment: Try adding an empty `__init__.py` file to the `Algorithms` subdirectory...

Comment: @jsbueno and zwer

Thanks a lot guys. It would've taken me ages to find this on my own (=

You guys are awesome!